# MathJax vertical space + too thick fraction lines

Tags: mathjax

When I use `MathJax`, sometimes the fraction lines got a different thickness (below imgage). Why?

Another question is how to increase the vertical space between the lines, because in `\begin{align} ... \end{align}` the lines are so close to each other and it's hard to read them (as you can see on the below sample image).

[image]

Comment: MathJaX doesn't use the same program as TeX so questions about MathJaX aren't really on topic here.  You will probably have more luck at the [MathJaX Help Forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users)

Comment: See my response [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4620/7798) for details of why this happens in MathJax.

Comment: Ps, you can use `\\[dimen]` to add extra space between lines of an alignment.  So `\\[5pt]` would add an extra 5 points of space between the lines at that breakpoint.

Comment: For everybody who encounters this issue. Say you have a presentation tomorrow and really want all fractions to appear at all costs, you can use your own definition of fractions (with thicker lines):
`\begin{align}\genfrac{}{}{1pt}{0}{a+b}{c+d}\frac{a+b}{c+d}`